# How to trigger click on ajaxSubmitButton

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have filter-from with ajaxSubmitButton.

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Show',Yii::app()->createUrl('office/ajaxFilter'),array('update'=>'#office-install'),array('id'=>'filterSubmit'))
```

And i want to submit it on pageLoad (to recive data using default filter values). How to trigger  click on ajaxSubmitButton?

using

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#filterSubmit').trigger('click');
}
```

raise redirect.

Comment: `return false;` should help you out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to trigger the click on `#filterSubmit` element to run some actions associated with it, but without having the page following the regular click, if so:

**UPDATE YOUR CODE TO THIS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // bind a click event to the button
  $('#filterSubmit').bind('click', function(e) {

    // the browser from following the click
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // trigger the click on the button
  $('#filterSubmit').trigger('click');

  // unbind the click event to allow the normal usage of that button
  $('#filterSubmit').unbind('click');
}
```

This assumes that you have some click events binded to the `#filterSubmit`... If that is not the case, perhaps a more elaborated question cold allow us to help you out!

---

**EDITED**

By the comment you've just post, you can do something like:

**YOU CODE** <sup>(with a minor fix)</sup>:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#filterSubmit').trigger('click');

}); // was missing ); here
```

**WITH Yii Framework**

```
<?php

// the script string
$ourscript = "$('#filterSubmit').trigger('click');";

// Yii’s registerScript
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
                            'filtersubmitclickscript',
                            $ourscript,
                            CClientScript::POS_READY
                          );

?>
```

Comment: Elaborate a bit more on your question!! Is the assumption provided on my answer correct?

Comment: I tried <?Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('onLoadSubmit',"  $('#filterSubmit').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#filterSubmit').trigger('click');

  $('#filterSubmit').unbind('click');
",CClientScript::POS_READY)?>

Comment: ajaxSubmitButton don`t work after that. So i decided to make simple ajax request on page load (actualy the same as ajaxSubmitButton reques )

Comment: Just edited my answer with an example on how to pass from the Jquery Document Ready to Yii’s registerScript. (still don't know if it is what you are trying to do...)

Comment: Yes, it`s that what i`m trying to do.  But i have already tried suggested method (

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been covered many times here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=click+trigger+jquery

You might get issues in several browsers with the trigger because of security restrictions.